# How do i stop the blocking?

Tags: c, function, block

Hey all I've asked this question a few times in the past few days but I just don't get it...I basically want to have the while loop for the Beep command executed in the background while the user can interact with the available case statements (only one shown..there are others)....i keep getting blocked and everytime i want the beep to make a sound constantly i block the rest of my program...I have to use Beep so please don't suggest any other functionality..

here's a sample code...

```
while( keypress != 'q' || keypress != 'Q')
{   
    x = Beep(x);
    while (x == 1)
       Beep(350,300);

    alarm_t current;
    keypress = _getch();

    switch(keypress){

        case 'h':
            sprintf_s(current.message,"high alarm");
            current.timeOfEvent = time(NULL);
            recordEvent(current);
            break;
```

Now...my issue is with the while loop and the Beep command....here is what i call to Beep(x)

```
int Beep(int y)
{ 
    return y;
}
```

So basically i am trying to call a function outside of my current cpp file to just compare x and y, and return y as being equivalent to x...i thought this might avoid blocking but it doesn't...

Comment: `while ( keypress != 'q' && keypress != 'Q')`

Comment: that causes the program to be blocked by the beep...

Comment: You've really got to stop putting while loops in while loops.  If you do it right, your upper loop is so fast that the users won't hear much difference if you just call Beep without the inner `while`.

Comment: if i remove that inner while loop then i only get one beep...and i only get another beep when there's a keypress...i want it to beep constantly

Comment: try to put some sleep in your whiles

Comment: the `while (x == 1) Beep(350,300);` could only terminate if beep manages to change the value of x. Which is not very probable (this is called a loop-invariant) . So the loop either executes zero times or infinitely.

Comment: how do i apply sleeps in my whites? and i agree wildplasser...but how do i get around it? i know the problem very well, i've posted three times about it but what can i do?

Comment: What does _getch() do when there is no input? Does it block until (valid) input, or does it return a "special" value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while loop around beep just won't work and `_getch` is blocking. So it will just block until there's a character.

Depending what platform you are on, you need something like `kbhit` (and if you google that you will find alternatives for other platforms). ie it's not standard C functionality and platform specific.

`kbhit` will return true or false depending if there is a character or not.

So you can do:

```
while(!key_is_quit(ch))
{
  Beep();
  if(kbhit())
  {
    ch = getch();
  // switch....
  }
}
```